# Refresh ng2-chart when new api call is made

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js, ng2-charts

The bar chart I have is populated from an API call. The API accepts a filter therefore, I would like for the chart data to be updated when an option is selected from a dropdown list. There is only data for 2022 so when another year is selected the chart is blank(which is as expected) however the legend still has the old data and is not blank.

When 2022 is selected again, the data is duplicated but only one bar is shown on the chart with extra space with no label and the legend shows the label twice for each bar. The expected behavior is that the chart has only one bar, one label in the legend and no extra space.

**"chart.js": "^3.6.0"**

**"ng2-charts": "^3.1.2"**

**Chart on page load**

[image: Chart on page load]

**Chart when another year is selected**

[image: Chart when another year is selected]

**Chart when 2022 is reselected**
[image: Chart when 2022 is reselected]

**report.component.html**

```
  <mat-select ngClass="w-25" [value]="currentYear" (selectionChange)="getSelectedYear($event.value)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let year of yearList" [value]="year">
            {{year}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

**report.component.ts**

```
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
import { ChartData, ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { UsageService } from 'src/app/services/report/usage.service';
import { usageStats } from 'src/types/ReportTypes';
import { ColorGeneratorService } from 'src/app/services/helper/color/color-generator.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-usage',
  templateUrl: './usage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usage.component.scss']
})
export class UsageComponent implements OnInit {

  monthLabels: string[] = [];
  chartInfo: any[] = [];
  yearList: number[] = [];
  currentYear: number = new Date().getFullYear();
  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart!: BaseChartDirective;

  // static chartdata

  chartData: ChartData<'bar'> = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: []
  };

chartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Monthly Report',
        font: {
          size: 22,
          family: 'Poppins'
        }
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          display: true
          font: {
            size: 16,
            family: 'Poppins',
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          display: true
          font: {
            size: 16,
            family: 'Poppins',
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        },
        ticks: {
          precision: 0
        }
      },

    }
  };
    




  constructor(
    private usage: UsageService,
    private colorGenerator: ColorGeneratorService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // Load the chart with data from the current year
    this.populateChart(this.currentYear);
  }


  getSelectedYear(year: number) {
       this.removeData(this.chart);
       this.populateChart(year);
  }


  removeData(chart: any) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset: any) => {
      dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
  }


  addData(chart: any, label?: any, data?: any) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset: any) => {
      dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
  }




  populateChart(selectedYear: number) {
    this.usage.getUsageReport(selectedYear,
      (stats: Array<usageStats>) => {

        console.log("Stats", stats);

        if (stats.length > 0) {
          stats.forEach((s) => {
            this.monthLabels.push(s.month);
            this.chartInfo.push({
              'label': s.service, data: [s.count],
              backgroundColor: this.colorGenerator.getRandomColor(),
              borderColor: this.colorGenerator.getRandomColor(),
              borderRadius: 20, hoverBackgroundColor:
                this.colorGenerator.getRandomColor(),
            });

            // Do not add duplicate years to the filter list
            if (!this.yearList.includes(s.year)) {
              this.yearList.push(s.year);
              this.yearList.push(2024);
              this.yearList.push(2023);

              // Sort the list in ascending order
              this.yearList.sort((a, b) => a - b);
            }
          });


          this.chartData = {
            labels: this.monthLabels,
            datasets: this.chartInfo
          }
            this.chart.update();
        }
      },
      (error: any) => {
        
      }
    );
  }


}
```

Comment: I think you should clear the array of "dataset.data" and then load new data every time you change the year. and then update the chart. Furthermore I would suggest to set the options only once due to are not changing when the year is changed.

Comment: Updated the question and screenshots based on your suggestion. It's a little better but not 100% yet

Comment: I see that you are still replacing the dataset object instead of using the same dataset. See statement "this.chartInfo.push({" and afterwards the assignment to  chartData . AFA I understood you have only 1 dataset (1 per year) to show.

Comment: A sample in codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/QWrLGbq

Comment: Data is not returned for all years at once it goes back and fetches the data for every year.

Comment: yes and forgive me if I misunderstand you. But you are showing only 1 year at once, therefore only 1 dataset. Therefore you should fill (and clear) always the same object defined in chart.data.datasets[0] (0 because if I understood well, you are showing only 1 dataset per year at once).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by clearing the arrays before populating so that the previous data isn't present

```
import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
import { ChartData, ChartOptions } from 'chart.js';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { UsageService } from 'src/app/services/report/usage.service';
import { usageStats } from 'src/types/ReportTypes';
import { ColorGeneratorService } from 'src/app/services/helper/color/color-generator.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-usage',
  templateUrl: './usage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./usage.component.scss']
})
export class UsageComponent implements OnInit {

  monthLabels: string[] = [];
  chartInfo: any[] = [];
  yearList: number[] = [];
  currentYear: number = new Date().getFullYear();
  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart!: BaseChartDirective;

  // static chartdata

  chartData: ChartData<'bar'> = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: []
  };

chartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Monthly Report',
        font: {
          size: 22,
          family: 'Poppins'
        }
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          display: true
          font: {
            size: 16,
            family: 'Poppins',
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          display: true
          font: {
            size: 16,
            family: 'Poppins',
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        },
        ticks: {
          precision: 0
        }
      },

    }
  };
    




  constructor(
    private usage: UsageService,
    private colorGenerator: ColorGeneratorService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // Load the chart with data from the current year
    this.populateChart(this.currentYear);
  }


  getSelectedYear(year: number) {
       this.removeData(this.chart);
       this.populateChart(year);
  }


  removeData(chart: any) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset: any) => {
      dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
  }


  addData(chart: any, label?: any, data?: any) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset: any) => {
      dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
  }




  populateChart(selectedYear: number) {
    this.usage.getUsageReport(selectedYear,
      (stats: Array<usageStats>) => {

   //Clear arrays used to store the chart details
    this.monthLabels = [];
    this.chartInfo = [];

        if (stats.length > 0) {
          stats.forEach((s) => {
            this.monthLabels.push(s.month);
            this.chartInfo.push({
              'label': s.service, data: [s.count],
              backgroundColor: this.colorGenerator.getRandomColor(),
              borderColor: this.colorGenerator.getRandomColor(),
              borderRadius: 20, hoverBackgroundColor:
                this.colorGenerator.getRandomColor(),
            });

            // Do not add duplicate years to the filter list
            if (!this.yearList.includes(s.year)) {
              this.yearList.push(s.year);
              this.yearList.push(2024);
              this.yearList.push(2023);

              // Sort the list in ascending order
              this.yearList.sort((a, b) => a - b);
            }
          });


          this.chartData = {
            labels: this.monthLabels,
            datasets: this.chartInfo
          }
            this.chart.update();
        }
      },
      (error: any) => {
        
      }
    );
  }


}
```